# Mock native method with JMock 2

Tags: java, jmock

Can I mock a native method with JMock 2? For example, mock this method from the `Thread` class

```
public final native boolean isAlive();
```

Writing tests in the usual way just fail with `not all expectations were satisfied` so it's implying not. It fails silently rather than tell me it's can't mock natives, so I'm asking here to be sure...

/Thanks

Comment: Consider using Mockito, it is better mocking framework.

Comment: Thanks but that's not really helpful